# npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR when install

Tags: node.js

In my server(CentOS 7.2) I install the dependencies:

```
npm install
```

But I get bellow error:

```
npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! unexpected end of file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-11T21_03_20_261Z-debug.log
```

in the `/root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-11T21_03_20_261Z-debug.log`, the info is bellow:

```
10234 verbose bundle EBUNDLEOVERRIDE: Replacing npm@1.4.29's bundled version of readable-stream with readable-stream@1.0.34.
10235 verbose unlock done using /root/.npm/_locks/staging-ace74a3b0cf47932.lock for /home/ubuntu/source_code_web/vue_admin_site/node_modules/.staging
10236 warn The package iview is included as both a dev and production dependency.
10237 warn npm@1.4.29 had bundled packages that do not match the required version(s). They have been replaced with non-bundled versions.
10238 verbose type OperationalError
10239 verbose stack Error: unexpected end of file
10239 verbose stack     at Gunzip.zlibOnError (zlib.js:152:15)
10240 verbose cwd /home/ubuntu/source_code_web/vue_admin_site
10241 verbose Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
10242 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
10243 verbose node v8.4.0
10244 verbose npm  v5.3.0
10245 error code Z_BUF_ERROR
10246 error errno -5
10247 error unexpected end of file
10248 verbose exit [ -5, true ]
```

I tried use：

```
npm cache clean
```

to clean the npm, but fails:

```
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-11T21_13_51_943Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the end, I delete the `node_modules`:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

and deleted the `package-lock.json`,
then re-install:

```
npm install
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 70):

Try cleaning the cache with the command  `npm cache clean --force` and retry your npm install.

Comment: We have this issue too. Clearing the cache fixes it. But it keeps breaking on subsequent builds. Do you know what the underlying issue is?

Comment: In my case the dependencies were over-ridding each other because of false import of external api's.

Comment: That seems to work for me too, but just for the record: I've also removed `package-lock-false` from my `.npmrc`. I'm not sure if this or cleaning the cache actually fixed the problem in my case. My npm is `6.4.1` on Windows.

Answer (score 16):

1. "npm cache clean --force"
2. "npm cache verify"

following steps helped me!! :-)

if problem still persist : "npm i npm"

Comment: It worked for me, dont forget to do the `npm i npm` if it fails on first 2 steps. :)

Comment: Thank you, only the first line wored for me.

Answer (score 6):

I was trying this on Windows 10 and the only solution that worked for me was updating npm by giving

**npm install npm@latest -g**

Comment: this solved my problem without removing cache or node_modules dir

Comment: After many trials of other answers even from GitHub and StackOverflow, this solution finally worked. Also, yarn add was able to install the package for me but it did not add it to the environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in npm GitHub

> Node 8.9.0+ (and 9+) fix an issue where streams are terminated early
>   in some scenarios. If you're getting this error upgrade to 8.9.

So you can just try to update your node and npm

Answer (score 2):

None of the listed solutions helped in my case. I solved the problem by manually removing the caches folder:

```
rm -rf ~/.npm/_cacache
```

Or if `npm` installed in the root folder:

```
sudo rm -rf /root/.npm/_cacache
```

Answer (score 1):

npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache

This is what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

1. The network caused the module to download the failure
2. Install a Taobao image and then it's fine:
   `npm install -g cnpm -- registry-https://registry.npm.taobao.org`
3. `cnpm install egg -- save`

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything related to npm still the problem persist then it might be caused due to some unwanted cache which are getting deleted in the ".apm" folder.
Follow these steps.

1. Goto -> C:\Users\Your_Username\.atom\.apm\_cacache
2. Delete all the files(tmp,content,index etc..)
3. Again try and install the package by command or atom.

This might work for you. :-)