# Connecting sqlite3 from Node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I get this error below when trying to connect sqlite3 from Node.js

PS C:\Users\cybertronprime\MySQL> npm install sqlite3

npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR

npm ERR! errno -5

npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\cybertronprime\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-

01T13_44_55_243Z-debug.log

PS C:\Users\cybertronprime\MySQL>

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this counts as duplicate, there was a similar issue on a CentOS system with the same errors. It could be a partial download or corrupted files. As here you are not connecting, but rather install the sqlite3 node module.

```html
npm cache clean --force
```

If this does not help see: [npm ERR! codd Z-Buff_Error when install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739985/npm-err-code-z-buf-error-when-install)