# unable to install angular cli npm -ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR npm ERR! errno -5 npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

Tags: angular, npm

C:\Users\darsh>npm -v
6.4.1

C:\Users\darsh>node -v
v10.14.1

C:\Users\darsh>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\darsh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-09T07_55_28_446Z-debug.log

getting these errors while installing angular cli

Comment: It seems like a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739985/npm-err-code-z-buf-error-when-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739985/npm-err-code-z-buf-error-when-install)

Answer (score 0):

try to clean cache by using: `npm cache clean`

if you unable to force clean by: `npm cache clean --force`

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

delete the `node_modules` directory:

```
rm node_modules
```

delete the `package-lock.json`, then re-install:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... you can try.

```
npm cache clean --force
```