# problem when installing mysql module using node.js

Tags: node.js

i downloaded Node.JS recently and im trying to install mysql module 
but this error keeps showing to me
`npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file`

how to fix it?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm ERR! code Z\_BUF\_ERROR when install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739985/npm-err-code-z-buf-error-when-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the cache using `npm cache clean --force`, and try again :)

If this doesn't work, try to remove node modules and reinstall your dependencies and try again.