# I installed express-session but failed

Tags: node.js

I installed express-session with `npm install express-session` but it failed.

```
PS E:\Node js\Express\session> npm install express-session
npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Q-ANH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-13T14_07_04_441Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm ERR! code Z\_BUF\_ERROR when install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739985/npm-err-code-z-buf-error-when-install)

Comment: Try to delete node_modules folder, then try installing again