# react-app installation error- npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to install React-App using "npx create-react-app myapp1" in my Visual Studio Code terminal. npx successufully got installed but I am getting error after that.[image: npm error]

I tried to use:

> npm cache clean

But that didn't worked. I even have cleared node modules . That too didn't changed anything.
Here are the contents of my log file-

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save',
1 verbose cli   '--save-exact',
1 verbose cli   '--loglevel',
1 verbose cli   'error',
1 verbose cli   'react',
1 verbose cli   'react-dom',
1 verbose cli   'react-scripts',
1 verbose cli   'cra-template' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.14.2
4 verbose npm-session afa38825e42ecc60
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react 588ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for react@latest fetched in 607ms
9 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom 626ms (from cache)
10 silly pacote tag manifest for react-dom@latest fetched in 630ms
11 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template 771ms (from cache)
12 silly pacote tag manifest for cra-template@latest fetched in 772ms
13 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-scripts 777ms (from cache)
14 silly pacote tag manifest for react-scripts@latest fetched in 782ms
15 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 1012ms
16 silly install loadIdealTree
17 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
18 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 1ms
19 silly install loadShrinkwrap
20 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 0ms
21 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
22 silly resolveWithNewModule react@16.13.1 checking installable status
23 silly resolveWithNewModule react-dom@16.13.1 checking installable status
24 silly resolveWithNewModule cra-template@1.0.3 checking installable status
25 silly resolveWithNewModule react-scripts@3.4.1 checking installable status
26 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/loose-envify 123ms (from cache)
27 silly pacote range manifest for loose-envify@^1.1.0 fetched in 124ms
28 silly resolveWithNewModule loose-envify@1.4.0 checking installable status
29 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign 125ms (from cache)
30 silly pacote range manifest for object-assign@^4.1.1 fetched in 126ms
31 silly resolveWithNewModule object-assign@4.1.1 checking installable status
32 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/prop-types 138ms (from cache)
33 silly pacote range manifest for prop-types@^15.6.2 fetched in 139ms
34 silly resolveWithNewModule prop-types@15.7.2 checking installable status
35 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/js-tokens 98ms (from cache)
36 silly pacote range manifest for js-tokens@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 fetched in 100ms
37 silly resolveWithNewModule js-tokens@4.0.0 checking installable status
38 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-is 121ms (from cache)
39 silly pacote range manifest for react-is@^16.8.1 fetched in 124ms
40 silly resolveWithNewModule react-is@16.13.1 checking installable status
41 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/scheduler 115ms (from cache)
42 silly pacote range manifest for scheduler@^0.19.1 fetched in 118ms
43 silly resolveWithNewModule scheduler@0.19.1 checking installable status
44 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-jest 131ms (from cache)
45 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-eslint 138ms (from cache)
46 silly pacote range manifest for babel-jest@^24.9.0 fetched in 140ms
47 silly resolveWithNewModule babel-jest@24.9.0 checking installable status
48 silly pacote version manifest for babel-eslint@10.1.0 fetched in 142ms
49 silly resolveWithNewModule babel-eslint@10.1.0 checking installable status
50 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fcore 152ms (from cache)
51 silly pacote version manifest for @babel/core@7.9.0 fetched in 156ms
52 silly resolveWithNewModule @babel/core@7.9.0 checking installable status
53 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fwebpack 160ms (from cache)
54 silly pacote version manifest for @svgr/webpack@4.3.3 fetched in 161ms
55 silly resolveWithNewModule @svgr/webpack@4.3.3 checking installable status
56 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin 103ms (from cache)
57 silly pacote version manifest for case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin@2.3.0 fetched in 105ms
58 silly resolveWithNewModule case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin@2.3.0 checking installable status
59 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/css-loader 113ms (from cache)
60 silly pacote version manifest for css-loader@3.4.2 fetched in 117ms
61 silly resolveWithNewModule css-loader@3.4.2 checking installable status
62 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dotenv 111ms (from cache)
63 silly pacote version manifest for dotenv@8.2.0 fetched in 112ms
64 silly resolveWithNewModule dotenv@8.2.0 checking installable status
65 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dotenv-expand 120ms (from cache)
66 silly pacote version manifest for dotenv-expand@5.1.0 fetched in 121ms
67 silly resolveWithNewModule dotenv-expand@5.1.0 checking installable status
68 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/camelcase 284ms (from cache)
69 silly pacote range manifest for camelcase@^5.3.1 fetched in 285ms
70 silly resolveWithNewModule camelcase@5.3.1 checking installable status
71 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-react-app 336ms (from cache)
72 silly pacote range manifest for babel-preset-react-app@^9.1.2 fetched in 342ms
73 silly resolveWithNewModule babel-preset-react-app@9.1.2 checking installable status
74 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-loader 343ms (from cache)
75 silly pacote version manifest for babel-loader@8.1.0 fetched in 350ms
76 silly resolveWithNewModule babel-loader@8.1.0 checking installable status
77 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-plugin-named-asset-import 353ms (from cache)
78 silly pacote range manifest for babel-plugin-named-asset-import@^0.3.6 fetched in 359ms
79 silly resolveWithNewModule babel-plugin-named-asset-import@0.3.6 checking installable status
80 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint 131ms (from cache)
81 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-config-react-app 144ms (from cache)
82 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fparser 408ms (from cache)
83 silly pacote range manifest for eslint-config-react-app@^5.2.1 fetched in 170ms
84 silly resolveWithNewModule eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1 checking installable status
85 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint/-/eslint-6.8.0.tgz 45ms (from cache)
86 silly pacote range manifest for @typescript-eslint/parser@^2.10.0 fetched in 439ms
87 silly resolveWithNewModule @typescript-eslint/parser@2.34.0 checking installable status
88 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for eslint@^6.6.0 zlib: unexpected end of file
89 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-extra 24ms (from cache)
90 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-loader 201ms (from cache)
91 silly pacote range manifest for fs-extra@^8.1.0 fetched in 27ms
92 silly resolveWithNewModule fs-extra@8.1.0 checking installable status
93 silly pacote version manifest for eslint-loader@3.0.3 fetched in 203ms
94 silly resolveWithNewModule eslint-loader@3.0.3 checking installable status
95 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-import 187ms (from cache)
96 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-flowtype 198ms (from cache)
97 silly pacote version manifest for eslint-plugin-flowtype@4.6.0 fetched in 203ms
98 silly resolveWithNewModule eslint-plugin-flowtype@4.6.0 checking installable status
99 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2feslint-plugin 490ms (from cache)
100 silly pacote range manifest for @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^2.10.0 fetched in 513ms
101 silly resolveWithNewModule @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.34.0 checking installable status
102 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-import/-/eslint-plugin-import-2.20.1.tgz 48ms (from cache)
103 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for eslint-plugin-import@2.20.1 zlib: unexpected end of file
104 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y 185ms (from cache)
105 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-react-hooks 171ms (from cache)
106 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^1.6.1 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...bQTjQD2nrK9ZcJAilbwIx'
107 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-react 184ms (from cache)
108 silly pacote version manifest for eslint-plugin-react@7.19.0 fetched in 186ms
109 silly resolveWithNewModule eslint-plugin-react@7.19.0 checking installable status
110 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/-/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y-6.2.3.tgz 15ms (from cache)
111 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.2.3 zlib: unexpected end of file
112 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/identity-obj-proxy 106ms (from cache)
113 silly pacote version manifest for identity-obj-proxy@3.0.0 fetched in 107ms
114 silly resolveWithNewModule identity-obj-proxy@3.0.0 checking installable status
115 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/html-webpack-plugin 141ms (from cache)
116 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/file-loader 154ms (from cache)
117 silly pacote version manifest for html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.11 fetched in 144ms
118 silly resolveWithNewModule html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.11 checking installable status
119 silly pacote version manifest for file-loader@4.3.0 fetched in 157ms
120 silly resolveWithNewModule file-loader@4.3.0 checking installable status
121 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jest 123ms (from cache)
122 silly pacote version manifest for jest@24.9.0 fetched in 126ms
123 silly resolveWithNewModule jest@24.9.0 checking installable status
124 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jest-resolve 101ms (from cache)
125 silly pacote version manifest for jest-resolve@24.9.0 fetched in 108ms
126 silly resolveWithNewModule jest-resolve@24.9.0 checking installable status
127 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen 154ms (from cache)
128 silly pacote version manifest for jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen@1.0.1 fetched in 155ms
129 silly resolveWithNewModule jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen@1.0.1 checking installable status
130 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jest-watch-typeahead 129ms (from cache)
131 silly pacote version manifest for jest-watch-typeahead@0.4.2 fetched in 133ms
132 silly resolveWithNewModule jest-watch-typeahead@0.4.2 checking installable status
133 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mini-css-extract-plugin 127ms (from cache)
134 silly pacote version manifest for mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0 fetched in 129ms
135 silly resolveWithNewModule mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0 checking installable status
136 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-flexbugs-fixes 94ms (from cache)
137 silly pacote version manifest for postcss-flexbugs-fixes@4.1.0 fetched in 95ms
138 silly resolveWithNewModule postcss-flexbugs-fixes@4.1.0 checking installable status
139 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pnp-webpack-plugin 143ms (from cache)
140 silly pacote version manifest for pnp-webpack-plugin@1.6.4 fetched in 144ms
141 silly resolveWithNewModule pnp-webpack-plugin@1.6.4 checking installable status
142 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin 156ms (from cache)
143 silly pacote version manifest for optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.3 fetched in 157ms
144 silly resolveWithNewModule optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.3 checking installable status
145 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-normalize 138ms (from cache)
146 silly pacote version manifest for postcss-normalize@8.0.1 fetched in 139ms
147 silly resolveWithNewModule postcss-normalize@8.0.1 checking installable status
148 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-preset-env 137ms (from cache)
149 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-loader 148ms (from cache)
150 silly pacote version manifest for postcss-preset-env@6.7.0 fetched in 140ms
151 silly resolveWithNewModule postcss-preset-env@6.7.0 checking installable status
152 silly pacote version manifest for postcss-loader@3.0.0 fetched in 152ms
153 silly resolveWithNewModule postcss-loader@3.0.0 checking installable status
154 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-safe-parser 120ms (from cache)
155 silly pacote version manifest for postcss-safe-parser@4.0.1 fetched in 122ms
156 silly resolveWithNewModule postcss-safe-parser@4.0.1 checking installable status
157 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils 106ms (from cache)
158 silly pacote range manifest for react-dev-utils@^10.2.1 fetched in 109ms
159 silly resolveWithNewModule react-dev-utils@10.2.1 checking installable status
160 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-app-polyfill 129ms (from cache)
161 silly pacote range manifest for react-app-polyfill@^1.0.6 fetched in 132ms
162 silly resolveWithNewModule react-app-polyfill@1.0.6 checking installable status
163 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve-url-loader 111ms (from cache)
164 silly pacote version manifest for resolve-url-loader@3.1.1 fetched in 112ms
165 silly resolveWithNewModule resolve-url-loader@3.1.1 checking installable status
166 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sass-loader 123ms (from cache)
167 silly pacote version manifest for sass-loader@8.0.2 fetched in 126ms
168 silly resolveWithNewModule sass-loader@8.0.2 checking installable status
169 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver 127ms (from cache)
170 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve 162ms (from cache)
171 silly pacote version manifest for semver@6.3.0 fetched in 129ms
172 silly resolveWithNewModule semver@6.3.0 checking installable status
173 silly pacote version manifest for resolve@1.15.0 fetched in 164ms
174 silly resolveWithNewModule resolve@1.15.0 checking installable status
175 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/style-loader 117ms (from cache)
176 silly pacote version manifest for style-loader@0.23.1 fetched in 122ms
177 silly resolveWithNewModule style-loader@0.23.1 checking installable status
178 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ts-pnp 115ms (from cache)
179 silly pacote version manifest for ts-pnp@1.1.6 fetched in 116ms
180 silly resolveWithNewModule ts-pnp@1.1.6 checking installable status
181 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/terser-webpack-plugin 120ms (from cache)
182 silly pacote version manifest for terser-webpack-plugin@2.3.5 fetched in 123ms
183 silly resolveWithNewModule terser-webpack-plugin@2.3.5 checking installable status
184 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/url-loader 143ms (from cache)
185 silly pacote version manifest for url-loader@2.3.0 fetched in 145ms
186 silly resolveWithNewModule url-loader@2.3.0 checking installable status
187 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack 127ms (from cache)
188 silly pacote version manifest for webpack@4.42.0 fetched in 146ms
189 silly resolveWithNewModule webpack@4.42.0 checking installable status
190 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-manifest-plugin 151ms (from cache)
191 silly pacote version manifest for webpack-manifest-plugin@2.2.0 fetched in 153ms
192 silly resolveWithNewModule webpack-manifest-plugin@2.2.0 checking installable status
193 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server 173ms (from cache)
194 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/workbox-webpack-plugin 129ms (from cache)
195 silly pacote version manifest for webpack-dev-server@3.10.3 fetched in 178ms
196 silly resolveWithNewModule webpack-dev-server@3.10.3 checking installable status
197 silly pacote version manifest for workbox-webpack-plugin@4.3.1 fetched in 131ms
198 silly resolveWithNewModule workbox-webpack-plugin@4.3.1 checking installable status
199 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents 126ms (from cache)
200 silly pacote version manifest for fsevents@2.1.2 fetched in 127ms
201 silly resolveWithNewModule fsevents@2.1.2 checking installable status
202 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
203 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 2492ms
204 silly saveTree myapp1@0.1.0
204 silly saveTree +-- cra-template@1.0.3
204 silly saveTree +-- react-dom@16.13.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- loose-envify@1.4.0
204 silly saveTree | | `-- js-tokens@4.0.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- object-assign@4.1.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- prop-types@15.7.2
204 silly saveTree | | `-- react-is@16.13.1
204 silly saveTree | `-- scheduler@0.19.1
204 silly saveTree +-- react-scripts@3.4.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/core@7.9.0
204 silly saveTree | | `-- resolve@1.15.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- @svgr/webpack@4.3.3
204 silly saveTree | +-- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.34.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- @typescript-eslint/parser@2.34.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- babel-eslint@10.1.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- babel-jest@24.9.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- babel-loader@8.1.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- babel-plugin-named-asset-import@0.3.6
204 silly saveTree | +-- babel-preset-react-app@9.1.2
204 silly saveTree | +-- camelcase@5.3.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin@2.3.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- css-loader@3.4.2
204 silly saveTree | +-- dotenv-expand@5.1.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- dotenv@8.2.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- eslint-loader@3.0.3
204 silly saveTree | | `-- fs-extra@8.1.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- eslint-plugin-flowtype@4.6.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- eslint-plugin-react@7.19.0
204 silly saveTree | | `-- semver@6.3.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- file-loader@4.3.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- fs-extra@8.1.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- fsevents@2.1.2
204 silly saveTree | +-- html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.11
204 silly saveTree | +-- identity-obj-proxy@3.0.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen@1.0.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- jest-resolve@24.9.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- jest-watch-typeahead@0.4.2
204 silly saveTree | +-- jest@24.9.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.3
204 silly saveTree | +-- pnp-webpack-plugin@1.6.4
204 silly saveTree | | `-- ts-pnp@1.1.6
204 silly saveTree | +-- postcss-flexbugs-fixes@4.1.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- postcss-loader@3.0.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- postcss-normalize@8.0.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- postcss-preset-env@6.7.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- postcss-safe-parser@4.0.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- react-app-polyfill@1.0.6
204 silly saveTree | +-- react-dev-utils@10.2.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- resolve-url-loader@3.1.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- resolve@1.15.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- sass-loader@8.0.2
204 silly saveTree | +-- semver@6.3.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- style-loader@0.23.1
204 silly saveTree | +-- terser-webpack-plugin@2.3.5
204 silly saveTree | +-- ts-pnp@1.1.6
204 silly saveTree | +-- url-loader@2.3.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- webpack-dev-server@3.10.3
204 silly saveTree | +-- webpack-manifest-plugin@2.2.0
204 silly saveTree | +-- webpack@4.42.0
204 silly saveTree | `-- workbox-webpack-plugin@4.3.1
204 silly saveTree `-- react@16.13.1
205 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
206 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
207 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
207 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
207 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
207 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
208 verbose stack ZlibError: zlib: unexpected end of file
208 verbose stack     at Zlib.(anonymous function).onerror (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:131:21)
208 verbose stack     at Unzip.write (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:255:31)
208 verbose stack     at Unzip.flush (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:222:10)
208 verbose stack     at Unzip.end (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:229:10)
208 verbose stack     at Object.end (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:415:21)
208 verbose stack     at PassThrough.onend (_stream_readable.js:628:10)
208 verbose stack     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
208 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:187:15)
208 verbose stack     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
208 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
209 verbose cwd C:\Users\Prinzu\Desktop\yawl\new\myapp1
210 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
211 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts" "cra-template"
212 verbose node v10.14.2
213 verbose npm  v6.4.1
214 error code Z_BUF_ERROR
215 error errno -5
216 error zlib: unexpected end of file
217 verbose exit [ -5, true ]
```

Even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739985/npm-err-code-z-buf-error-when-install) also adviced to delete the package-lock file. But seems like it is automatically deleting that file as I am getting-
[image: error]

Comment: Did you try to delete node_modules, package-lock.json and run `npm cache clean --force && npm install`

Comment: @hurricane  From where? . I deleted it from the folder I was trying to install react and the npm-cache folder in the C drive.

Comment: you need to do that in your project root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted all my  node_modules, package-lock.json files from root folder.